Bipolar analog latch circuit needed
I am struggling with the required circuit design which should latch its output if the signal (from range ±10 V DC) reaches ±1 V (or a certain predefined threshold). I have found on this site a circuit (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/203799/243495) showing the unipolar design using voltage comparators (picture shown), but I need this for both signal polarities at the input.

Any idea about how to design the required circuit? This might be a window comparator latch?
It doesn't have to be this particular circuit, any other proposal is also welcome.

It sounds like your window is bracketed by $\pm 1:\text{V}$ around the ground reference and that any excursion outside this bracket triggers a latch. What supply rails do you have available? What kinds of devices are excluded from view? (D FF?) Etc.

Slavisa Micic - Hi, Where did that schematic originally come from? In order to comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you next to that material. If the original source is online (webpage, PDF, video etc.) then please [edit] the question & add its name & link (URL). However there are additional requirements to comply with the CC BY-SA license, if you copied it from elsewhere on Stack Exchange - see here for the attribution you must add. TY

@periblepsis, I can confirm what you have just stated. Everything at the input, going outside of the brackets triggers a latch. I would prefer +5VDC for the supply (as I have a very fast TLV3201 available) but would sacrifice this for the sake of simplicity, thus having +/- 15VDC already present on the board. There are no excluded components but the focus is on the simplicity and the number of components since I have a very limited space left on the board. I am thinking of using the circuit shown together with a full wave precise rectifier but I prefer a few components solutions.

@SlavisaMicic So, this suggests that you need to move the $\pm 1:\text{V}$ upward into the range of $0:\text{V}$ to $5:\text{V}$, somehow. Or else include more rail voltages, one of which must be negative. This might be done with three resistors: a pull-up of about $17:\text{k}\Omega$ to $5:\text{V}$, a pull-down of about $540:\Omega$, and an input resistance of about $10:\text{k}\Omega$, yielding an output between about $100:\text{mV}$ and $200:\text{mV}$. Just as an example. Not necessarily as what you should do.

You can use a window comparator that outputs Low when the input sigal is outside of bounderies + Latch:
The bounderies are set with R1.
The 100K-s resistors have to be calibrated (have precisely same resistance), the +10V and -10V have to be equal also, otherwise the bounderies will be shifted.


+1. Might I suggest a reset switch between 2N3904 base and -10V?

I will probably take this approach since it is easy to make symmetric modifications.

I won't answer the entire question. But I'll focus on how you might move the input voltage into range of your \$+5\:\text{V}\$ rail and ground.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
If \$R_1=R_2=10\text{k}\Omega\$ then \$R_3=560\:\Omega\$. And this means that you can expect something like this:

In other words, the input is clearly shifted into range. This would allow you to set up a reasonable Schmitt trigger with the right bracketing to get what you need. For the range of \$\pm1\:\text{V}\$, find:

So the window is clear from the above. You can set up your arrangement to work with this range, correctly, and get what you need.
Just a thought.
The first image shows a wider range for your input source and what it looks like at the output. The second image shows just your specific \$\pm 1\:\text{V}\$ around zero-ground. And the output there shows your hysteresis box for a Schmitt trigger, if you want to go that route.
All I wanted to do here is to show you how you can passively bring your input into range of your existing positive-only voltage range.
It can be done.


I need this for both signal polarities at the input

Convert the input using a precision bridge rectifier to a unipolar signal. Example from here: -

